# Selenium scraping dynamic infinite scroll without AJAX

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

**Intent:** Scrape company data from the [Inc.5000 list](https://www.inc.com/inc5000/list/2020) (e.g., rank, company name, growth, industry, state, city, description (via hovering over company name)).

**Problem:** From what I can see, data from the list is dynamically generated in the browser (no AJAX). Additionally, I can't just scroll to the bottom and then scrape the whole page because only a certain number of companies are available at any one time.  In other words, companies 1-10 render, but once I scroll to companies 500-510, companies 1-10 are "de-rendered".

**Current effort:** The following code is where I'm at now.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get('https://www.inc.com/inc5000/list/2020')

all_companies = []

scroll_max = 600645 #found via Selenium IDE

curr_scroll = 0
next_scroll = curr_scroll+2000

for elem in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('franchise-list__companies'):
    while scroll_num <= scroll_max:
        scroll_fn = ''.join(("window.scrollTo(", str(curr_scroll), ", ", str(next_scroll), ")"))
        driver.execute_script(scroll_fn)
        all_companies.append(elem.text.split('\n')) 
        print('Current length: ', len(all_companies))
        curr_scroll += 2000
        next_scroll += 2000
```

Most SO posts related to infinite scroll deal with those that either maintain the data generated as scrolling occurs, or produce AJAX that can be tapped.  This problem is an exception to both (but if I missed an applicable SO post, feel free to point me in that direction).

**Problem:**

1. Redundant data is scraped (e.g. a single company may be scraped twice)
2. I still have to split out the data afterwards (final destination is a Pandas datafarame)
3. Doesn't include the company description (seen by hovering over company name)
4. It's slow (I realize this is a caveat to Selenium itself, but think the code can be optimized)

Comment: problem 1 - use a set to ensure unique data is retrieved, and scroll slowly, problem 2 - build the data frame as you scroll, problem 3 - hover each company you see and save that data before moving on, problem 4 - yes, you gotta deal with it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is loaded from external URL. To print all companies, you can use this example:

```
import json
import requests


url = 'https://www.inc.com/rest/i5list/2020'
data = requests.get(url).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for i, company in enumerate(data['companies'], 1):
    print('{:>05d} {}'.format(i, company['company']))
    # the hover text is stored in company['ifc_business_model']
```

Prints:

```
00001 OneTrust
00002 Create Music Group
00003 Lovell Government Services
00004 Avalon Healthcare Solutions
00005 ZULIE VENTURE INC
00006 Hunt A Killer
00007 Case Energy Partners
00008 Nationwide Mortgage Bankers
00009 Paxon Energy
00010 Inspire11
00011 Nugget
00012 TRYFACTA
00013 CannaSafe
00014 BRUMATE
00015 Resource Innovations

...and so on.
```

Comment: Andrej, can you tell me how you found that URL?  I had been trying to find one for a while, but apparently I wasn't looking in the right place(s) :/

Comment: @alofgran I opened Firefox developer tools -> Network tab and observed, where the page is making requests. This url was biggest one, regarding downloaded size.

Comment: Well...this is embarrassing.  Haha.  I'd done exactly that in Chrome, but for whatever reason, I missed it.  Thanks, Andrej!